# How to extract value out of an array of Ordereddicts?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a csv file rows where one column has ordereddicts in them, how do I create a new column extract a single element of each ordereddict using python (3.+)/ pandas(.18)?

Here's an example. My column, `attributes`, has `billingPostalCodes` hidden in ordereddicts. All I care about is creating a column with the `billingPostalCodes`.

Here's what my data looks like now:

```
 import pandas as pd
 from datetime import datetime
 import csv
 from collections import OrderedDict

 df = pd.read_csv('sf_account_sites.csv')
 print(df)
```

yields:

```
 id    attributes  
  1    OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001d000001tKZmWAAW')])), (u'BillingPostalCode', u'85020')])  
  2    OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001d000001tKZmWAAW')])), (u'BillingPostalCode', u'55555')])
  ...
```

I know on an individual level if I do this:

```
dict = OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/001d000001tKZmWAAW')])), (u'BillingPostalCode', u'85020')])

print(dict['BillingPostalCode'])
```

I'll get 85020 back as a result.

What do I have to get it to look like this?

```
 id    zip_codes  
  1    85020
  2    55555
  ...
```

Do I have to use an apply function? A for loop? I've tried a lot of different things but I can't get anything to work on the dataframe.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to work out, but the problem is resolved by doing the following:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row["attributes"]["BillingPostalCode"], axis = 1)
```

The trick here is to note that `axis = 1` forces `pandas` to iterate through every row, rather than each column (which is the default setting, as seen in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

> **DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None,
>   args=(), **kwds)**
>
> Applies function along input axis of DataFrame.
>
> Objects passed to functions are Series objects having index either the
>   DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the columns (axis=1). Return type
>   depends on whether passed function aggregates, or the reduce argument
>   if the DataFrame is empty.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - func : function Function to apply to each column/row
> - axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
>   - 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
>   - 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row

From there, it is a simple matter to first extract the relevant column - in this case `attributes` - and then from there extract only the `BillingPostalCode`.

You'll need to format the resulting DataFrame to have the correct column names.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I'm I'm getting `TypeError: ('string indices must be integers', 'occurred at index 0')` when I try this. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @AndrewKraemer I tested this out on the example you cited, and it worked well. What version of Pandas are you using? I'm on Pandas 0.18. I suspect in an older version of Pandas row indexing like this happens with integers, not column names. Try `row[1]["BillingPostalCode"]` instead.

Comment: I am indeed on .18. I ran what you recommended and got the same issue. I can upload the actual dataset if it would help. It seems that the data in the attributes column is saved as a string, where it needs to be a collections.OrderedDict to work. Not sure how to convert the string to OderedDict though.

Comment: Actually, this works! I tried it on production and I got the results! Thank you so much!